# How to execute cron job as non-root user under Ubuntu inside Docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, cron

This is the Dockerfile of an image I'm trying to create. The non-root user is simulating the host user on the local machine.

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic
RUN apt-get -yqq update && apt-get -yqq install cron passwd openssl strace
RUN groupadd -g 1000 hostuser && useradd -l -u 1000 -m -s /bin/bash -p $(openssl passwd -1 test1) -g hostuser hostuser
COPY hello-cron /etc/cron.d/hello-cron
RUN sudo chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/hello-cron
COPY hello-cron-root /etc/cron.d/hello-cron-root
RUN sudo chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/hello-cron-root
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
COPY cron.allow /etc/cron.allow
#CMD /usr/sbin/cron -L 15 && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
CMD strace /usr/sbin/cron -f -L 15
```

This is the file hello-cron:

```
* * * * * hostuser echo "Hello World" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

This is the file hello-cron-root:

```
* * * * * root echo "Hello World Root" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

This is the file cron.allow:

```
hostuser
```

When I build and execute the image ONLY the job executed under root gives some output. strace did not help much. Any ideas?

Unfortunately I can't use Alpine or something else. I need to make this work using Ubuntu Bionic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far this is the only thing that works in this setup:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic
RUN apt-get -yqq update && apt-get -yqq install cron passwd openssl sudo
RUN groupadd -g 1000 hostuser && useradd -l -u 1000 -m -s /bin/bash -p $(openssl passwd -1 test1) -g hostuser hostuser
COPY hello-cron-root /etc/cron.d/hello-cron-root
RUN sudo chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/hello-cron-root
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
COPY cron.allow /etc/cron.allow
COPY hostuser-run /usr/local/bin/hostuser-run
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/hostuser-run
CMD /usr/sbin/cron -L 15 && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

This is hostuser-run:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo -H -s -u 'hostuser' echo "We are running as $USER"
```

This is the file hello-cron-root:

```
* * * * * root /usr/local/bin/hostuser-run >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

To summarize - given that only root cron jobs are working under docker to execute stuff under different user use helper script with `sudo -u`.